# How to import data from one database to another

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, database

I've got an SQL Statement running in C#, which fetches data from a table in **Database A** in MySQL, and inserts it into a table in **Database B**.

I am carrying out the select and insert in one SQL statement, as the data is too much to hold in memory.  My question is, how would I specify the connection string of the destination database (Database B).

My SQL statement is like so:

```
sql = INSERT INTO Database_B.Table (SELECT * FROM Database_B.Table);
```

As it is right now, I am specifying the connection string of Database A only:

```
sourceDatabaseConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=Database_A;Uid=root;Pwd=root;";

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(sourceDatabaseConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.CommandTimeout = 0;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Now the thing is that this is working perfectly.  But both databases are on the same server and have the same credentials.  How would I handle it if the database is placed elsewhere?

Comment: I think your only option is linked servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using OUTFILE syntax.  It was the only way I could think of solving this without using linked servers, which is not practical for my situation, since I do not have access over the databases, and just accept connection strings from users.

What my solution does is first carry out a **SELECT** statement and write the data to a file.  Next my **INSERT** statement picks up from the file, and inserts into another table.

This approach thus avoids putting millions of records in memory, and since they are two separate statements, I am able to bind each one with different connection strings - hence problem solved :)

The code is similar to this:

```
statement1 = SELECT myFields INTO OUTFILE @file;

statement2 = LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE @file INTO TABLE myTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I quote the post of Mahmoud Gamal who suggested this answer in another post:

> Use SELECT ... INTO ... with a fully qualified table names
>   database.schema.object_name, like this:

```
 USE DatabaseName;    
 SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.schemaname.Tablename INSERT INTO
 AnotherDatabase.schemaname.AnotherTablename;
```

> Then you can use ADO.net or other API to execute this query from C#.

Source: [Inserting result of a SQL query from one database to another in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683209/inserting-result-of-a-sql-query-from-one-database-to-another-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is technically what I am doing right now. What I need is for it to be done programatically based on the connection strings of the source and destination database.

Comment: What are the informations you know for the 2 databases ?

Comment: I would not know much unfortunately.  I would like to copy data from one database (any database in any location) to another database (any database in any location).  This is possible if I split it up into two separate queries, however I cannot store any data in memory as I am dealing with millions of records.

Comment: So how do you get the informations about ConnectionString data, Databasename, Tablename etc ? Are those informations given to you via something like xml or will there be a user-input ? I'm a little bit confused how you want to send data from one database to another if you are lacking informations about 1 or both of the databases.

Comment: I have the connection string of the source database, and the connection string of the destination database.

Comment: The fact that you have that much data that you cannot store any of them locally makes the thing very tricky. Your best shot is to use linked Servers and 4 part notation queries as "artm" suggested. I try to find a different solution, if I do so I will update.